# SQL PHP Query, getting the value "email"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In the following code how can I retrieve the column "email" from the database "users".

we get $Username and $password from a form we filter them do all the checks and submit the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

  IF( $result->num_rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;
$_SESSION['sess_email']=$result->email; }
```

Looks like the column email is not getting Selected, I can print $_SESSION['sess_user'] so there is a match in the database but I thought by doing "SELECt *..." I would be picking all the columns in that row. How can I access the "email" value in the selected row ( without doing a new query SELECT email from...)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can we have your database structure?

Comment: the database is just 4 columns, id, username, password,email I am wondering if possible to reference that column "email" from $result without doing a new sql query to assign it to a session value without having to do SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE username=$username

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but please consider storing passwords hashed with the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. And read about SQL-injection when you have a quiet minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

You can't access column values directly through `$result` because it is object of type `mysqli_result`. You have to first fetch result array from it and then try to access column value like this:

```
if($result === TRUE)
{
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;
        $_SESSION['sess_email']=$row["email"]; 
}
$result->free();
```